# Java - log4j XML Configuration for appending Server Name

Tags: java, log4j

I want to append a server name to my log, so how can I do this?
I also want to delete files based on age, say after 365 days.

Any help will be of great value.

Comment: what do you mean by "append Server name" ?

Comment: I have only one log file which logs details for many servers in an clustered environment. so when logging starts i want to add the server name.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question see my comment to your question.

For your second question use `RollingFileAppender` and set `maxBackupIndex` to the number of files you want to keep. If you need help defining it let me know ...

Comment: you want [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) for date based rolling

Comment: maxBackupIndex deletes the file based on number. But I want to delete the log files based on the number of days i.e say after 365 days and the number of files generated during that period is not consistent,it varies

Comment: What about @Matt suggestion ?

Comment: The appender I am using is TimeAndSizeRollingAppender